# Possibility of natively adding other calendars to iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I am living in Iran and there are hundreds of thousands of iOS users here that like me, unfortunately, although they have paid a lot for iDevices, still cannot utilize iOS calendar app, cannot set reminders, cannot set the device date in the calender they are used to and they are faced with many side limits.

My question is that, is there a possibility to add custom calenders, other than Gregorian and a few more which can be selected in iOS 7 so that they become default calender of device?
I'm looking for the possibility of custom (in this case [Persian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar)) calendar becomes added via an standard interface, a plug-in or any other way to the OS.

p.s.1: What is seems to be added as a calendar for Persian people is NOT actually Persian calendar; it is just Gregorian calendar being displayed in Persian language.

p.s.2:   Please forgive me if I described the context before directly asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Persian Calendar (taghvim-e-shamsi) is available on iOS but it is hidden for some reasons!
As much as i know, It will come out with new iOS(V 8.0) at this fall.

Otherwise you can use shamsi calendars on app store which have reminders.

Comment: Hope it will be available